# Overloading method with similar types

Tags: c#, overloading

I have read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229029%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) article on MSDN and my eye caught this:

"DO NOT have overloads with parameters at the same position and similar types yet with different semantics."

i have a method that has 2 overloads:

```
public bool myMethod(MyObject obj, Guid user)
public bool myMethod(MyObject obj, Guid group)
```

The point here is that my method grants access to an object to either a group or a user. Since the guideline gets violated here I was wondering if my approach is good enough or should I define a new method (or a third option)?

Comment: Currently your code wouldn't even compile... you can't overload a method with the same parameter types in the same order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you expect to happen if someone calls `.myMethod(new MyObject(), new Guid())` on such an object? How is the compiler meant to know what to do?

There's no way for you to answer that, and there's no way for the compiler either.

Method overloading is used because two methods are similar enough in what they do that having the same name is an aid to human comprehension, though they do that task with different parameters. If they don't essentially do the same thing, they should have different names so people writing code that use them will know what each does. If they do do essentially the same thing, then you don't need two such methods.

You **could** reverse the order of the parameters in one, to make them distinct, **but this would be a very bad idea**, because it won't be clear which is which from looking at calling code.

What you would be best to do is either something like:

```
public bool MyMethodByUser(MyObject obj, Guid user)
{
   /* ... */
}
public bool MyMethodByGroup(MyObject obj, Guid group)
{
   /* ... */
}
```

Or (perhaps better) something like:

```
public bool MyMethod(MyObject obj, User user)
{
   Guid userID = user.Guid;
   /* ... */
}
public bool myMethod(MyObject obj, Group group)
{
   Guid groupID = group.Guid;
   /* ... */
}
```

So that users and groups are represented by different types.

Comment: Thanks, I will go with the last option (make the `Group` and `User` objects).

Answer (score 3):

Your options are:

**Rename Methods**

This would be my recommendation.

```
public bool myMethodByUser(MyObject obj, Guid user)
public bool myMethodByGroup(MyObject obj, Guid group)
```

**Change Parameter Types**

Extract the Guids into their own class. Potentially overkill in this situation but you may already have these objects for `User` and `Group`.

```
public bool myMethod(MyObject obj, User user)
public bool myMethod(MyObject obj, Group group)
```

**Change Parameter Order**

This is a really nasty hack and I only mention it because it's possible to do. Doing this is confusing to the caller and breaks the guidelines you posted. Additionally, what would you do if you needed a third method, for example passing in a role `Guid`?

```
public bool myMethod(MyObject obj, Guid user)
public bool myMethod(Guid group, MyObject obj)
```

Comment: Since your answer is essentially the same as mine, I'll +1 it if you expand on just how nasty that nasty hack was. I mentioned it too, but there is a definite danger in mentioning this approach, in that somebody might actually do it.

Comment: @JonHanna Thanks Jon, I've made a tweak and moved that option to the bottom!

Comment: +1 so :) Always a dilemma, the fact that one knows something is technically possible, and therefore belongs in a full answer, vs the fact that one knows it's a really bad idea.

Comment: Provided we don't mention that you can use the `goto` statement in c#, we should be OK... Oops!

Answer (score 0):

Currently your code contains syntax error. you can't overload a method with the same parameter types in the same order. you can only overload a method with different types, by changing order or parameter or by number of parameters

Comment: Also this is not an answer to his question.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you have same method name and same arugement so IDE will not allow you to compile your Programme, eiether you have to change the method name or you have to add one more argument in any one of your method.